# How to open skype in one window 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, skype

How can i open skype like windows for example when we open skype on ubuntu it has multiple windows

- For contacts
- For current call
- For chat

is it possible to open skype like we open skype on xp / 7 / 8 i.e in one window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Skype implementation in Linux does not support a "single window mode" (yet).

You could try [SkypeTab](http://keks-n.net/skypetab/). It displays all chat UIs in one window (tabbed).

Comment: Thats Quite Helpfull answer. Its pretty close to what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless Microsoft will make such "one windowed" release of Skype for linux, I think there is no solution for this. This question should be asked to Skype developers, not Ubuntu.

Comment: i asked here cz i thought as there was an option on windows os to change weighter one window skype or multiple

Comment: i think you are right

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very easy. Use this application: https://github.com/haskellcamargo/skype-unofficial-client. Seems it is just WinSkype clone.

Comment: Nice, but I see a note that they don't support video calls (jan 2017).